# Atualizar dados de duas planilhas sem sobrescrever no arquivo fonte

Tags: python, pandas

Eu leio as planilhas do arquivo no seguinte modo:

```
sheet_Pessoas = pd.read_excel("meus_dados.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
sheet_Clientes = pd.read_excel("meus_dados.xlsx", sheet_name=1)
```

Depois eu adiciono uma linha no Dataframe de cada planilha desse modo:

```
sheet_Pessoas.loc[-1] = [Nome,int(CPF),int(Idade),int(Nasc),Login,Senha,Cargo]  # adding a row
        with pd.ExcelWriter("meus_dados.xlsx") as writer:
            sheet_Pessoas.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Pessoas', index = False)

sheet_Clientes.loc[-1] = [Empresa,int(CNPJ),Resp,Login,Senha]  # adding a row
        with pd.ExcelWriter("meus_dados.xlsx") as writer:
            sheet_Clientes.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Clientes', index = False)
```

Porém quando vou salvar a planilha no mesmo arquivo, ela sobrescreve todas as planilhas existentes. Se eu tenho a planilha `Pessoas` e `Clientes` e eu quero atualizar a planilha `Clientes`, quando salvo no mesmo arquivo `meus_dados` só aparece a planilha `Clientes`, a planilha `Pessoas` foi sobrescrita.

Gostaria de saber como posso atualizar as planilhas do meu arquivo sem que elas sobrescrevam.

Answer (score -1):

O ExcelWriter suporta o modo append:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("meus_dados.xlsx", mode='a') as writer:
```

Comment: Eu já tentei, não suporta esse modo. Eu uso spyder na versão 2.